# (not)implies sign as edges in tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I would like to make a graph in tikz as in [image]

However I would like to have an `implies` symbol instead of an arrow. How can I make a figure such as above but with implies (as well as `not implies` signs) as edges?

Comment: By implies do you mean a `\Rightarrow` ? (ie one with a double horizontal bar?

Comment: Did you try `\tikz \graph[edges=double] { a -> { b, c} -> d };`?  Is that what you need?

Comment: @Thruston: Thanks a lot,+1. (Wonder why I could not find this in the manual) and suppose one also needs a `not implies` sign i.e. the sign as above but with a slanted line segment that cuts through it, is it ok to overlay or is there a more direct and elegant way like the one you have suggested? Cheers

Comment: I'd suggest that you create the graph you want with `edges=double` and use some form of edge label for the not sign.  If you update the question with your effort, you might get some more detailed suggestions or answers.

Comment: @Thruston: Thanks very much indeed. I see that there's some "scoring out" possible as well. Shall try to do on my own first, if unsuccessful shall again ask for help by modifying. Cheers

Comment: You can use a decoration to put the slash midway.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `double` and `implies` (Note: the credit goes to [@percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51022/not-implies-not-leftarrow-description-in-the-middle-of-an-arrow-in-tikz-cd/51024#51024) for `not implie` command (i.e. `degil`).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzset{degil/.style={
            decoration={markings,
            mark= at position 0.5 with {
                  \node[transform shape] (tempnode) {$\backslash$};
                  }
              },
              postaction={decorate}
}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,>=implies]
 \graph  {
  a ->[double] {b,c} ->[double,degil] d
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard,arrows}
\tikzgraphsset{
  implies/.style={edges={double, double equal sign distance, -implies}},
  not implies/.style={implies,
    edge node={ node [sloped, xscale=-1] {$\backslash$} }
  },
  !/.style={not implies}
}
\begin{document}
\tikz\graph [implies] {
  a -> {b, c} ->[!] d;
};
\end{document}
```

[image]