# Help creating simple diagram

Tags: diagrams, flow-charts

I want to create a little diagram that looks like:

[image]

with `$\implies$` (double-lined arrow) for the arrows.  And I'd like to be able to write things on the arrows if possible.

How can I do this?  I've never used latex to create a diagram before!

Comment: Are you preparing an LaTeX document or do you just want to generate this picture and use it somewhere else?

Comment: Maybe a good start: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184563

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I want it to be part of an article I'm writing

Comment: And as said before, I would start reading https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf. Look for **19 Specifying Graphs** in the documentation (p. 256 in version 3.0.1a).

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the TikZ package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). It has become the de-facto standard drawing tool within LaTeX. The picture you gave could be written as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (0, 0) (a) {(a)};
\node at (2, 0) (b) {(b)};
\node at (4, 0) (c) {(c)};

\draw [double, ->, bend right, auto, swap] (a) to node {label 1} (b);
\draw [double, ->, bend right, auto, swap] (b) to node {label 2} (a);
\draw [double, ->, auto] (c) to node {label 3} (b);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and would render as [image]

Now, what is happening here? You might consider the `tikzpicture` the canvas on which to draw. The three `\node` commands create points on the canvas at the given coordinates `(0, 0)`, `(2, 0)`, and `(4, 0)`, respectively (the first number being the horizontal coordinate from left to right and the second one the vertical, from bottom to top). For later reference, these are called `a`, `b`, and `c`, respectively and drawn as such, with parentheses.

The `\draw` commands are responsible for the arrows. We’ll ignore the options for a moment and pretend the command was `\draw (c) to node {label 3} (b)`. This draws a line from the point we call `c` to the point `b`. In order to label the line, we create another node ad hoc using `node {label 3}`, where the thing in braces is the text to appear next to the line.

The options to the `\draw` command do the following:

- `double` draws two lines instead of one to make them appear like the “implies” arrow, as you requested.
- `->` specifies the arrow’s tips. That is, no tip at the beginning (straight line `-`, and an arrow tip at the end, `>`.
- `bend right` is for the curvature. `bend left` is also possible. Note that both arrows are bent right.
- `auto` positions the line’s label cleverly. Try compiling the example without the option: The label will be written *on* the line instead of next to it.
- `swap` controls whether the label should appear to the left or to the right of the line. If neither line had the `swap` option, the labels would be set between the lines, with little spacing between them. Try it out!

TikZ is a intimidatingly powerful package. When learning to use it, you should definitely follow the package author’s invitation to follow the tutorials at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

A short code with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd, amsmath}

\begin{document}\begin{tikzcd}
(a) \rar[Rightarrow, bend right, "f"] & \lar[Rightarrow, bend right, swap, " g"] (b) & \lar[Rightarrow, swap, " h "](c)
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]