# two questions about simple diagram

Tags: diagrams, tikz-arrows

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline= (a).base][>=stealth,>=implies]
\node[scale=1.4] (a) at (0,0){
\begin{tikzcd}
    \text{(a)}  \rar[Leftrightarrow]  
    & [1.8em] \text{(b)}  
    & [2em]  \text{(c)}\lar[Leftarrow]\arrow[ddl,Rightarrow]\footnotesize\text{(i,ii, or iii)}\\
    & \vspace{-5mm}  \\&\text{\hspace{1mm}(b)$^\prime$}\arrow[uu,Leftrightarrow] 
    \end{tikzcd}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces this:
[image]

Questions:

(1) How can I make the diagonal arrow start at (c), as it normally would without "(i,ii, or iii)"?

(2) The arrow from (b) to (c) needs a line through the center, similar to what `$\centernot\implies$` produces:

[image]

Comment: (1) A dirty solution could be add `& \hspace{-3em}`  before of "(i,ii, or iii)"

Comment: @Fran that works perfectly! Now I just need an answer to (2)

Comment: @Fran For (1) I think `\arrow[ddl,Rightarrow,start anchor=south west]` is better. (I'm working on the second point).

Comment: @CarLaTeX Sure, that's why I said "dirty" (I have little memory for the right anchor tikz syntax, and I did not have time to search it). BTW,+1

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

This is what I suggest to you:

1. use `start anchor=south west` option
2. put a `/` on the arrow (as a "fake" label, *edit*: egreg's answer make me realize that a simple `/` is enough, instead of an inverted `\backslash` as in my previous version).

By the way: why are you nesting a `tikzcd` (which is a `tikzpicture`) within another `tikzpicture`?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzcd}
        \text{(a)}  \rar[Leftrightarrow]  
        & [1.8em] \text{(b)}  
        & [2em]  \text{(c)\footnotesize(i,ii, or iii)}\arrow[l, Leftarrow, "/" {yshift=7pt, scale=1.2}]
        \arrow[ddl,Rightarrow,start anchor=south west]\\
        & \vspace{-5mm}  \\&\text{\hspace{1mm}(b)$^\prime$}\arrow[uu,Leftrightarrow] 
    \end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use [this answer by Percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51024/) for the negated arrow:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51024/
\tikzset{
  negated/.style={
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position 0.5 with {\node[transform shape] (tempnode) {$/$};},
    },
    postaction={decorate},
  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=4em,row sep=4em,inner xsep=0pt]
\text{(a)} \arrow[r,Leftrightarrow] &
\text{(b)} \arrow[d,Leftrightarrow] \arrow[r,Rightarrow,negated] &
\text{(c) (i, ii, or iii)} \arrow[dl,Rightarrow,start anchor=south west] \\
& \text{(b)\makebox[0pt][l]{$'$}} % no width for the prime
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution doesn't come to mind. I thought of `\not` (which didn't work well) but not of `/`.

Comment: Thanks @CarLaTeX and egreg.  Now my only problem is deciding which to use...